# Setting permission Android Receiver permission

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver in code which is a receiver for configuration changes

`ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED`

```
IntentFilter iff = new IntentFilter();
iff.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(my class, iff);
```

Do I need to set permissions for Android based ones like these? Is it a security threat at all? If I do need to, how do I set it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to set permissions for Android based ones like these?

Not that one.

> Is it a security threat at all?

Configuration changes, such as rotating the screen, are not usually considered to be a security threat.

Comment: What about something like this ? android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED this is from the Android system as well. Basically ones that are sent out by Android. I am worried about those

Comment: @user3547028: Usually, if receiving a specific broadcast requires that you hold a permission, it will be documented. `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` [requires a permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). `ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` does not. `LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION` [is not documented as requiring a permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION), though I have not tried that one personally.